# How can I fix "error: cannot find symbol" in Jenkins?

Tags: java, ant, build, compiler-errors

I am working in a `Continuous Integration` environment using `Jenkins + Netbeans (Java code) + Git`. I am trying to use `Jacoco` plugin with *Ant* tasks in order to do code covering. I have a build, different than the default one (build.xml). I created another, but when I run the "compile-test" ant task this is what I get:

```
compile-tests:<br>
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\CITestApp\bin\classes-tests</br>
[javac] C:\CITestApp\test\citestapp\logic\CalculatorTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol</br>
[javac]     private Calculate calculator;
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Calculate
[javac]   location: class CalculatorTest
[javac] C:\CITestApp\test\citestapp\logic\CalculatorTest.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         calculator = new Calculate();
[javac]                          ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Calculate
[javac]   location: class CalculatorTest
[javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\CITestApp\jacocorep.xml:29: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

How can I know what this error means:

> "error: cannot find symbol"

Comment: First of all this error is being thrown by the javac task, it does not appear to be a problem related to Jacoco, because the code must be built before it can be tested. I would suggest you provide the relevent snippet from the "jacocorep.xml" file. This is a classpath problem.

Comment: ok, I will try to take a look at the classpath again, however, I will put the classpath code line. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

These are the targets in the ant build that I created in where I define the classpath of the tests that will be compiled:

`<target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac fork="true" debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>`>

`<target name="compile-tests" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}-tests"/>
        <javac fork="true" debug="true" srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}-tests" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.10.jar"/>
        <path refid="application"/>
    </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>`

I have another build (this is the default project build.xml) in which I compile and execute the unit tests in my project. I have these two ant builds in the project root, so I don't really know if the classpath is correct.

I defined the classpath in the begining like this:

`<path id="classpath">
     <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="org/osgi/**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="application" location="{classes.dir}"/>`